# Navigating using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect to my home route upon submitting my axios request to the api and gathering a valid response. As can be seen, Im trying to use context but in this case i get an error "context is undefined". How can i navigate to my home route in this case? I tried using history.push but that does not seem to work either. Any ideas would be much appreciated?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Home from './Home'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'

class SignUp extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:9000/signup',{
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data.success)
        this.context.router.push('/home');
      })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" render={() => (
          <div>
            <h1> Sign Up</h1>
            <input name="email" placeholder="enter your email" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
            <br/>
            <input name="password" placeholder="enter your password" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
            <br/>
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>submit</button>
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
          </div>
        )}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

SignUp.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default SignUp
```

Comment: The function needs to be binded so the appropiate context is conveyed to the function handler e.g.
`this.handleClick.bind(this)()`
or more simply put, `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I binded this to it and still context is undefined !!!

Comment: have you tried 
import { browserHistory} from 'react-router';
  browserHistory.push('/');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting routes and dynamically routing in React-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434041/nesting-routes-and-dynamically-routing-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

Routes should be always level above of all your components (or containers). Then, when a component is "inside" router (in your case BrowserRouter) it will gain access to its context.

Also you have  inside render function of another  wich does not make sense at all.

So something like this should work:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Home from './Home'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom'

class SignUp extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    axios
    .post('http://localhost:9000/signup',{
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data.success)
        this.context.router.push('/home');
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <h1> Sign Up</h1>
      <input name="email" placeholder="enter your email" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
      <br/>
      <input name="password" placeholder="enter your password" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
      <br/>
      <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>submit</button>
      </div>
      )
   }
}

SignUp.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}; 

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
      </BrowserRouter>)
    }
 }

 export default App;
```

And of course move SignUp component to standalone file to keep the project clean and well structured.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ! moving the routes to the top level has fixed the issue of context not being defined; as in i'm not getting an error anymore but it doesn't direct me to my home component (clicking the button keeps me on the same '/' route)

Comment: Actually I think I got my hopes up. I wasn't even running the onClick function properly which is why context wasn't throwing an error. After getting the onClick to work properly, I'm yet again getting context is undefined even after binding it !