# Confusion With React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to use the router object in child component but unable to do so. My main goal is to change the route after successful login. In react router v4 I can not use the history object directly.

My main goal is to use `this.context.router` so I cam make the route transition.

Here is my application code ( I stripped out most of them just added what I think is needed) If you need more information please comment.

### Router

I have doubts about how I am adding components to route. But this is the only way I have found to use layout. So if you have any advice on this I will appreciate it.

```
<Router>
    <Switch>

        <Route path="/login" render={ () => ( <LayoutEmpty {...data} children={ <Login user={this.props.user} /> }  /> ) } />

        <Route exact path="/" render={ () => ( <LayoutApp {...data} children={ <Dashboard user={this.props.user} /> }  /> ) } />

        <Route path="*" component={LayoutNotFound} />

    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now Lets just talk about the login component. Inside the component there is not context object passed.

I have added contextTypes like this

```
Login.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
};
```

But that gives me only empty object as constant. Not route object is passed.

( let me know if you need code for login component but I think I have problem how I used `<Route>`)

Comment: See this to use nested route and routing dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434041/nesting-routes-and-dynamically-routing-in-react-router-v4/44434648#44434648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up refactoring my code and passing the history object down to the Smart component (container) level.

### My Refactored router looks like this

```
<Router>
    <Switch>

        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

        <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />

        <Route path="*" component={LayoutNotFound} />

    </Switch>
</Router>
```

After that I am importing my `Layout` component to containers ( `Login`, `Dashboard` ) and pass down history object as a props to those containers if they are requiring it.

### Container (Smart component)

```
import React from 'react';
import LayoutApp from '../containers/LayoutApp'

    class Dashboard extends React.Component{
    ...
    render(){   
            return (    
            <LayoutApp history={this.props.history} title="Dashboard">  
             ...
```