# Right way to route with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my React project, I have:

1. A Login component without header & sidebar components [login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Hzz.png)
2. A Dashboard component with a header, a footer and other child components that all render within the dashboard component [dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG0hF.png)
3. An Error page component

Question:
How should I construct my router to start from the login page and when I click on login, the router takes me to the dashboard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion With React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590511/confusion-with-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

I can point you to a nice medium article that also helped me to understand react routing.
https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf

For an example what i would do is

```
<Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
<Route exact path="/dashboard" component={DashboardComponent} />
<Route path="/dashboard/something" component={AnotherComponent} />
```

Then inside that DashboardComponent you can add your header and sidebar. And also other components.
If you need routes like

/dashboard/some_other_thing

You have to define the relevent  inside the DashboardComponent

Comment: Nice one but the login page should be in the home route which is the landing page. How should it be implemented as such?