# How to redirect an user to a different url when history object of react-router is not accessible

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

How should I redirect an user to a different url when I cannot get an access to history props of react-router?

What I want to do is when an user clicks an log-out link on the navigation menu, the user get redirected to the root path '/'.

```
handleAuthentication(event) {
    this.props.toggleAuthenticationStatus(() => {
        // I want to redirect an user to the root path '/' in this callback function.
    });
}
```

handleAuthentication method is called when an user clicks an login/logout link on the navigation menu.

```
toggleAuthenticationStatus(callback) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            return { isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn }
        },
        callback()
    );
}
```

Then, when handleAuthentication method in the NavigationMenu Component, it calls toggleAuthenticationStatus method in App Component that changes the state of Login/Logout and run callback function which is defined in the handleAuthentication method in the NavigationMenu Component.

Is it ok to run "window.location.href = '/'" directly?
Does it mess up the react-router history object???

Could anyone please how I should implement user redirect in a right way?

## App Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import NavigationMenu from './NavigationMenu';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Secret from './Secret';
import Top from './Top';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        };
        this.toggleAuthenticationStatus = this.toggleAuthenticationStatus.bind(this);
    }


    toggleAuthenticationStatus(callback) {

        this.setState((prevState, props) => {
                return { isLoggedIn: !prevState.isLoggedIn }
            },
            callback()
        );

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <NavigationMenu isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} toggleAuthenticationStatus={this.toggleAuthenticationStatus} />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/secret' render={(props) => <Secret isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} {...props} />} />
                        <Route path='/' component={Top} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

## NavigationMenu Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavigationMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
    }

    handleAuthentication(event) {

        this.props.toggleAuthenticationStatus(() => {

            // I want to redirect an user to the root path '/' in this callback function.

        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li><Link to='/'>Top</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/secret'>Secret</Link></li>
                <li><Link to='/login' onClick={this.handleAuthentication}>
                    {this.props.isLoggedIn === true ? 'Logout' : 'Login'}
                </Link></li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default NavigationMenu;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting routes and dynamically routing in React-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434041/nesting-routes-and-dynamically-routing-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

I found the method 'withRouter' in react-router. 
This seems the solution in my situation.
I'm going to try using it.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest
>   's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter
>   will re-render its component every time the route changes with the
>   same props as  render props: { match, location, history }.