# Redirection Issue in React JS Component

Tags: reactjs, redirect, conditional-statements, jsx

I am trying to redirect to other component via conditional statement in our component file.

**Snippet of myfile.js**

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
render(){
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            return(
                <Redirect to='/Myaccount' />
            );
        }   
    }
```

When the condition is true, it's changing the browser's url but the content is not loading. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this answer, I suppose this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434041/nesting-routes-and-dynamically-routing-in-react-router-v4/44434648#44434648

Comment: same, redirecting ......url changed in browser but page content not loading....

Comment: did you make use of withRouter, Also do you get any error or you have the matching route

Comment: yes i used "withRouter" as ..>>>>> `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`  >>>>>>`componentDidMount() {
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            this.props.history.push('/Myaccount');

        }
    }`>>>>>>`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (withRouter(Login));`...............................And I m not getting any error in console

Comment: Try this `import { withRouter } from 'react-router';`

Comment: tried....but giving same result..

Comment: Does it reload if you refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off using `history.push` Something like the following.

```
if (isLoggedIn()) {
   return(
       this.props.history.push("/Myaccount");
   );
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't return that though, nor would you have it in the render function

Comment: @Drum > this.props.history.push("/Myaccount"); >>> I tried but also not working ....