# Using browserHistory.push to change Route dynamically doesn't work with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to do a simple redirect in a function...

I tried this:

```
Router.browserHistory.push('/dashboard');
```

But then I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

whats my fail?

Comment: Whats your react-router version

Comment: "react-redux": "^5.0.5",     "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",

Comment: Check the answer on the duplicated question. browserHistory is not available form react-router-dom package from v4 , and is separated to history package. You can rather make use of withRouter and navigate with `history` prop

Comment: will you post your comment as answer so I can vote it up and mark it as useful answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new `browserHistory` won't work because `<BrowserRouter>` creates its own history instance, and listens for changes on that. So a different instance will change the url but not update the `<BrowserRouter>.`

`browserHistory` is not available form `react-router-dom` package from `v4` , and is separated to `history` package.

**Navigating with WithRouter**

You can rather make use of `withRouter` Higher Order Component and `navigate` with `history` prop

From the **[official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)**

You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest `<Route>'s` match via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter` will re-render its component every time the route changes with the same props as `<Route>` render `props: { match, location, history }.`

Sample snippet

```
import {withRouter} from "react-router"; 

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ...
   changeRoute = () => {
        this.props.history.push('/dashboard)
   }
   ...
}


 export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```

Also see this answer for more info on nesting and dynamically routing in react-router-v4

[Nesting routes and dynamically routing in React-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434041/nesting-routes-and-dynamically-routing-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you should use this new approach for `v4` `react router` but if you are looking for a quick workaround you can use context.
```javascript

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    // redirect to dashboard
    redirectToDashboard = () => {
        this.context.router.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
}

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}
```

This should do the trick