# React router sub nested components failing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am usinf react/redux and I am trying to get the routes working. It is a disaster. I have encountered nearly every bug/issue that you can find and yet no correct solution.

My index.js looks like this:

```
const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   applyMiddleware(thunk, promise)
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(createBrowserHistory(), store)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
                    <Route component={UserLayout}>
                        <Route exact path="/user/dashboard" component={UserDashboardPage} />
                        <Route exact path="/user/users" component={UserUsersPage} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I first had a  where Switch now is and that didn't work. Without the switch I get an error saying that Router may only have 1 child.

I want a login page that uses SimpleLayout and I want 2 url's user dashboard and user users that uses SimpleLayout and a sub layout UserLayout.

How can I get this done? Btw Do I access the url like /user/dashboard or /#/user/dashboard

Comment: which version of react-router are you using? Note that version 4 is fundamentally different from version 3 and earlier. As it stands, it looks like you have a mix of both.

Comment: You are trying to use react-router's v4 syntax in the form of react-router v3 structure.
You should be creating the subroutes that are a part of UserLayout inside UserLayout and not in your app level.

Comment: I think this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434041/nesting-routes-and-dynamically-routing-in-react-router-v4/44434648#44434648

Answer (score 0):

I now have this:

```
 <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <SimpleLayout>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                <Route path="/user">
                    <UserLayout>
                        <Route exact path="/user/dashboard" component={UserDashboardPage} />
                    </UserLayout>
                </Route>
            </SimpleLayout>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
</Provider>
```

I changed path="/" into path="/login". Now /login and /#/login doesn't work.

Also UserLayout is always visible even though it should only be visible when accesing a url that starts with /user.

Comment: Please consider to not answer your own question in the case of a clarification. Instead, edit it.

Comment: I tried that however stackoverflow doesnt allow long comments therefore I could only put my reponse here.

Comment: I do not mean to write a comment. You can also edit your question after you submitted it. A question needs to solve a problem. I would edit your question and then write in the comments "I adapted the question..."

Answer (score 0):

Your index.jsx should contain this inside the BrowserRouter:

```
  <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
  <Route path="/user" component={UserLayout}/>
```

And inside UserLayout:

```
  <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.url}/dashboard} component={UserDashboardPage}/>
```

React-Router v4 lets you define routes on the fly when you need them and not in a higher/config level.

Im not sure what does SimpleLayout stands in your app.