# React Router 4 - Defining Layout routes with no paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm facing issues trying to define pathless layout routes (which were possible in react router 3).
Basically what Im trying to achieve is something like:
In my index.js:

```
 <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>
```

In my App component define the layouts

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="" component={AuthLayout}/>
    <Route path="" component={MainLayout}/>
</Switch>
```

now because they are simply layouts, I want them to perform some functionality and define their nested routes, e.g

in the AuthLayout:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path={`${match.path}/sign-up`} component={SignUpContainer}/>
     <Route exact path={`${match.path}/login`} component={LoginContainer}/>
                                <Route component={SignUpContainer}/>
</Switch>
```

and In MainLayout:

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}/explorer`} component={ExplorerContainer}/>
//more routes 
      <Route component={NotFoundContainer}/>
    </Switch>
```

Now I know that it wont work because switch will always hit the first item, and without Switch it will render both components.
What I want to achieve is a shallow url so I dont want to define routes for the layouts. It was possible in RRTR 3 but I just cant figure out if I can do it in RRTR 4

just for reference in 3 I did it like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRedirect to="login"/>
            /*Profile Management Flows*/
            <Route path="" component={AuthLayout}>
                <Route path="login" component={LoginContainer}/>
                <Route path="sign-up" component={SignUpContainer}/>
                <Route path="forgot-password" component={ForgotPasswordContainer}/>
                <Route path="reset-password" component={ResetPasswordContainer}/>
                <Route path="on-boarding" component={OnBoardingContainer}/>


            </Route>
```

Any advice? should I just give up and add a path to each layout? should I maybe stick to RRTR3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you won't be able to do exactly what you did with React Router 3. I think something similar could be accomplished with the following:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/(login|signup|forgot-password|reset-password)" render={({ location }) => (
    <AuthLayout>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={/* ... */} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={/* ... */} />
          {/* ... */}
        </Switch>
    </AuthLayout>
  )} />
  <Route path="/" component={MainLayout} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: seems like that the closest thing to what Im looking for, feels like a hack but since I cant find anything better, Ill take it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend placing all your routes in a single switch and specify what layout to use inside each container. It will be easier to maintain.

```
<Switch>
     <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpContainer}/>
     <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
     <Route path="/explorer" component={ExplorerContainer}/>
     <Route path="/" component={MainLayout} />
</Switch>
```

If you would like to protect routes from unauthorized users you can use a **Higher order component**. I explained how can this be achieved in here: [React router v4 - Authorized routes and components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379934/react-router-v4-authorized-routes-and-components/46381726#46381726)

I found the following article on React Router 4 very helpful: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf