# Route authorization HOC cause to remount children 3-times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm using an HOC component to restrict access to the route for non-logged users. The problem that this HOC remount children components while mounting or re-rendering when access this route directly from url(on the app first load). For example I have a 3 times `did mount` in the `PaperWorkProgress` component.

Route definition:

```
<Route path="/paperwork/progress" component={RequireAuth(PaperWorkProgress)}/>
```

Here the HOC code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {

    // check if token exists in storage
    componentWillMount() {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (!token) {
        const {pathname, search} = this.props.location;
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/signin',
          search: `?redirect_to=${pathname}${search}`,
        });
      }
    }

    // additional check
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.loggedIn) {
        const {pathname, search} = this.props.location;
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/signin',
          search: `?redirect_to=${pathname}${search}`,
        });
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {loggedIn: state.session.loggedIn};
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try putting it in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I explained in details on how an auth HOC can be used wisely here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379934/react-router-v4-authorized-routes-and-components

Comment: @MatthewBarbara My HOC based on your solution but without a context feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question may be from a while ago already, but I just encountered the same problem.

In the end I found out that my **HOC function was actually called on every route change**.

What helped for me was to **create the authorized component only once** on initialization:

```
const AuthorisedDashboard = requireLogin(Dashboard);
```

and then later just use it

```
<Route path="/dashboard" component={AuthorisedDashboard} />
```

Or, you know, I guess you could just export the component with the HOC function already applied if it is only ever used in authorised mode...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will make a difference about the re-rendering problem, but your code feels wrong.

First, you seems to have 2 source of truth, your redux store and the localStorage, which complicates things. If you want to "hydrate" your store from previous navigation information, you should use the createStore "preloadedState" argument, not checking everytime in your component. Cf [Redux doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer) and this video from the creator of Redux himself [Video for persisting and rehydrating State](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage). Once your state comes only from your store it starts to be more simple.

Second,

When you push to the history object inside the component, It feels like you are mutating the component own props (as history is a prop). That feels weird to me and could be the root of your problem.

Why not use the Redirect component inside your render method like this instead ? cf [React router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). The component will looks like this (obviously you would need to change your Login component too, like in the docs)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"; 

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {
    render() {
      return !this.props.loggedIn ? (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: this.props.location }
          }}
          {...this.props}
        />
      ) : (
        <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
      );
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return { loggedIn: state.session.loggedIn, ...ownProps };
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

Comment: I'm using localStorage because on the app first load `state.session.loggedIn` still doesn't exists and fills only after `refresh token' action and it's always goes to redirect.