# requireAuth with react-router v4 and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I have HOC for check is logged user.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function requireAuthComponent(store, Component, redirectTo = '/') {
  return class RequireAuthComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const state = store.getState();
      const auth = state.auth;

      if (auth.logged) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }

      return <Redirect to={redirectTo} />;
    }
  };
}
```

And route

```
import PrivatContainer from './container/PrivatContainer';
import requireAuth from '../../components/requireAuth';

export default store => ({
  path: '/privat',
  exact: true,
  component: requireAuth(store, PrivatContainer),
});
```

PrivatComponent

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ auth: { logged }, toggleLogin }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Privat Route</h1>
    <h3>User is {logged.toString()}</h3>
    <button onClick={() => toggleLogin()}>Logout</button>
  </div>
);
```

When first enter on route all work fine, but when I change store with `logged: false`, I still stay on this component(route) because route call once and don't update on store update, how it fix or subscribe `RequireAuthComponent` on store update ?

Comment: I explained in details how an [Auth HOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379934/react-router-v4-authorized-routes-with-hoc) can be written. Please let me know if you find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not properly, so if you have better idea please tell me :)

```
export default function requireAuthComponent(store, Component, redirectTo = '/') {
  return class RequireAuthComponent extends React.Component {
    state = {
      listener: null,
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      const listener = store.subscribe(() => {
        this.forceUpdate();
      });

      this.setState({ listener });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      const { listener } = this.state;

      listener();
      this.setState({ listener: null });
    }

    render() {
      const state = store.getState();
      const auth = state.auth;

      if (auth.logged) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }

      return <Redirect to={redirectTo} />;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You can connect your HOC component to Redux with 'connect' function. This way you don't need manually to subscribe and unsubscribe, and your component will be changed on state change. If you still need an example, I can post it as answer.